# Transition between matrices of full rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Let   $A$,$B$ $ \ $ be two $n \times n$ real matrices of full rank
and
  $C$ a matrix generated with segment formula $C= (1-t)A+ tB$, where $0 <t  <1 $
(so in some sense $C$ is "between" $A$ and $B$ as an internal point of segment $AB$).

- Is there a method of checking whether any $C$ is also a full rank matrix
  $ - $ **other** one than just writing determinant $\det(C(t))$ and checking
  whether $det(C(t)) \neq  0$ for all $t$?
- Maybe if general case is too hard to tackle some method for orthogonal
  matrices exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $t \ne 1$ you have
$$
\frac{1}{1-t} C B^{-1}
=
A B^{-1} - \frac{t}{t-1} I,
$$
where $I$ is an appropriate identity matrix.

So $C$ is *not* full rank precisely when $\dfrac{t}{t-1}$ hits one of the eigenvalues of $A B^{-1}$.

Comment: so it is sufficient to use only eigenvalues of    $AB^{-1}$ ?... and that means for example that for orthogonal matrices the only possibility of loosing full rank is for $t=1/2$ ?

Comment: I would say so, yes.

Comment: Andreas, as I understand your great answer  the formula provides events of loosing the rank also for any real $t $ not just  from interval $(0;1)$ and additionally: the formula can be used  starting from eigenvalues also for detection all loosing rank matrices C  (with the calculation of $t$) lying on the "line" through $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: @Widawensen. thx. Yes, I believe this to be the case.

Comment: The 'symmetric' complement to the Andreas' answer - the condition is equivalent to:  $\dfrac{t-1}{t}=1-\dfrac{1}{t}$ hits one of the eigenvalues of $BA^{-1}$. On the whole line $AB$ consisting mainly of non-singular matrices it seems there is maximum only $n$ points representing singular matrices..

Comment: The other conclusion from your formula Andreas is that for  $0<t<1$ we have $ 1-(1/t) <0 $ so if happens that $BA^{-1}$ has only positive eigenvalues then for sure $C$ is a matrix of full rank.. Is it a proper conclusion?

Comment: @Widawensen, sorry, I am taken by other things, will possibly consider later.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion.