# Triangle made from full rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is related to the question [Transition between matrices of full rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166866/transition-between-matrices-of-full-rank)

Suppose we have in matrix space (I treat matrices here as vectors describing points in some $n \times n$ dimensional space)  three real square matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3$ that all are of full rank and any matrix $P$, lying on the segment $A_1A_2$ or $A_2A_3$ or $A_3A_1$ between these matrices, is also of full rank.

(what is equivalent to the fact that this matrix $P = t_i{A_i}+{t_iA_j}$  where $t_i,t_j$ are positive and $t_i+t_j=1$)

- Does it mean that any matrix $D$ in the interior of $\triangle ABC$ located in the two-dimensional plane determined by these matrices is
  also of full rank?
- If not what condition should be stated additionally to satisfy non-singularity for all these internal matrices?

Matrix $D$ is treated as an internal point of $\triangle ABC$ if the equation $D= t_1A+t_2B+t_3C$ is satisfied for some positive $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$  constrained by the equation  $t_1+t_2+t_3=1$.

Comment: 1) There is no reason that the full rank property is preserved ; there are many counter-examples. 2) little remark: It is not a hyperplane (dimension $n^2-1$) but a 3 dimensional subspace of the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ok just plane, two dimensional however, I suppose ( 3 points)

Comment: No: the set of matrices of the form $t_1A+t_2B+t_3C$ is 3-dimensional. (think to $A$, $B$,$C$ as there vectorized equivalent form as $1 \times n^2$ long vectors).

Comment: @JeanMarie But they are additionally constrained by  $t_1+t_2+t_3=1$ what gives I suppose two-dimensionality.. think of analogy with **two** points in 3d space - they determine one-dimensional line, it's not required that point $(0,0,0)$ belongs to that line..

Comment: You are right, I had not paid sufficient attention.

Comment: @JeanMarie In this question I'm simply interested whether results from the linked previous question can be somehow extended into more complicated case ( two-dimensional plane instead of one-dimensional line)

Comment: It might be notable that the matrices of deficient rank form an [$(n^2-1)$-dimensional](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45159/how-to-calculate-the-degrees-of-freedom-of-an-r-ranked-matrix-with-the-size-be) variety in $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Thank you for this extending knowledge comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is no.  We can take an example directly from the complex numbers, effectively: consider
$$
A_1 = I, \quad A_2 = \pmatrix{\cos 2\pi/3 & -\sin 2 \pi /3\\ \sin 2 \pi /3 & \cos 2 \pi /3}, \quad 
 A_3 = \pmatrix{\cos 4\pi/3 & -\sin 4 \pi /3\\ \sin 4 \pi /3 & \cos 4 \pi /3}
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.  Verify that all matrices on the segment connecting $A_i,A_j$ are invertible (in particular, it is useful to note that $\det (\begin{smallmatrix} a&-b\\b&a \end{smallmatrix}) = a^2 + b^2$).  However, we find that
$$
\frac 13 (A_1 + A_2 + A_3) = 0
$$

Comment: ..hmm... so it seems that for 3 points situation wrt preserving non-singularity is much worse that for two points... it's hard to find criterion ...probably only some additional constraints (?) could guarantee that all matrices-"points in the region" would be non-singular..

Comment: @Widawensen I don't think that we can be so lucky as to really leverage the two-matrix case.  You should post something about the full problem

Comment: the full problem is in avoiding singular matrices when we generate some real matrix  or a set of matrices (for example from experimental data) and we want to know how they are distanced from singularity..

Comment: @Widawensen that's not really enough information to go on. Anyway, I'm saying you might get better results if you made a new question about that directly, explaining what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: o.k. I'll think it over and post some day a problem about singularity. For now I just wanted to grasp some intuition about this variety which was mentioned by you... Maybe you know some additional links, all new pointers could be helpful..

Comment: Don't really have much besides what I gave you.  A result you might find useful is as follows: the set of positive definite matrices is convex.  So, if each of the $A_i$ is positive definite, then the matrices on the interior of their convex hull are also positive definite (and therefore have full rank).

Answer (score 1):

Another counter-example:

$$\pmatrix{2 & 2\\ 2 & 2}=\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\pmatrix{3 & 0\\0 & 3}+\pmatrix{3 & 3\\3 & 0}+\pmatrix{0 &3 \\3 & 3}\right)$$

is rank one, whereas the other matrices are rank-2.